# electric pair mode not getting detected

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm not able to activate the electric pair mode in emacs with command such as:

```
 M-x electric-pair-mode
```

Even something like `M-x describe-function electric-pair-mode` is not working.
What is wrong?

Comment: which emacs version are you using? It's included into the emacs 24. What is the result of invoking M-x electric-pair-mode?

Comment: Alright. I'm using emacs23, I suppose it's not included by default in this version. It is simply showing [No Match] message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use a [paredit mode](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit) instead.

You can enable it for some modes as indicated in their doc. Or you can enable it for all modes:

```
(load-file (expand-file-name "/path/to/paredit.el"))
(mapc (lambda (mode)
    (let ((hook (intern (concat (symbol-name mode)
                    "-mode-hook"))))
      (add-hook hook (lambda () (paredit-mode +1)))))
      '(emacs-lisp lisp inferior-lisp))
```

Or switch to emacs 24 where the electic-pair-mode is included into the distribution.

EDIT: Answering to your question. Curly bracket is defined in their code:

```
(define-paredit-pair ?\( ?\) "round")
(define-paredit-pair ?\[ ?\] "square")
(define-paredit-pair ?\{ ?\} "curly")
(define-paredit-pair ?\< ?\> "angled")
```

If it doesn't work for you you may have a conflict with another minor mode. Enabled minor modes are listed at the beginning if you invoke `M-x describe-mode` .

Comment: But it doesn't work with the curly braces. How do I fix that?

Comment: I added some info in my answer

Answer (score 0):

It's new in Emacs-24.1 (and relies on a new feature of Emacs-24.1, so you can't just use Emacs-24's electric.el in Emacs<24).